# Using jQuery to populate a DIV with the content from another DIV in same wrapper

Tags: jquery, this, selector

I been using jQuery for a while, but cant seem to gert my head round this...

I have a HTML layout like so:

```
  <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="accordionButton">
              <h2 class="profiletitles">Requested <?php $count = 0; ?></h2>
              <span class="trainingHeaderCount"></span>
            </div>
            <span class="postCount">12</span>
</div>
```

And I am trying to populate the `<span class="trainingHeaderCount"></span>` with the `<span class="postCount">12</span>`.

What I have so far is:

```
$('span.trainingHeaderCount').html($(this).parent().parent().find('.postCount').html());
```

But its not loading anything into the DIV. It masy be something to do with the misuse of the "this" but not sure..

Thanks

Comment: exactly that is the problem.. you have to put again span.trainingHeaderCount as a selector

Comment: Depending on the context of that code, `this` could be pretty much anything.

Comment: @JamesG: In your code, `$(this)` is undefined. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```
$('span.trainingHeaderCount').html($(this).parent().parent().find('.postCount').html());
```

`$(this)` is undefined.

Try this:

```
$this = $('.trainingHeaderCount')
$this.html($this.parent().parent().find('.postCount').html());​
```

### [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/JGwL5/)

Comment: The value of `this` depends on the context of the code, but it's impossible for `$(this)` to be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function to `.html()`, and inside of that function `this` will refer to the current element that's having its HTML set. For example:

```
$('span.trainingHeaderCount').html(function() {
    return $(this).parent().parent().find('span.postCount').html();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var spans = $('span.trainingHeaderCount');

$.each(spans,function(){
   $(this).html( $(this).parent().next().html() );      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('span.trainingHeaderCount').html(function(){
     return $(this).parent().siblings('.postCount').text()
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QYnDF/)

Answer (score 0):

This would work better if you made your wrapper a class, that way you could have multiple on the page: (you'd have to change #wrapper to .wrapper)

```
 ​$('#wrapper').each(function(index, element){
    $(element).find('.trainingHeaderCount').html($(element).find('.postCount').html());
    });​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And this way you can move the markup around on the page if you need to change spans to divs and back, etc.